# Rendering barcode with zend in kohana

Tags: php, zend-framework, kohana, barcode

I am using zend library to render bar code and it works as I'm getting bar code using:

```
<img src="<?php echo '/controller/print/'.$id.'/'.$barcode; ?>">
```

Where bar code settings are:

```
public static function generate_barcode($id, $factor = 1, $backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF', $barHeight = 50, $fontSize = 10)
{
    $code = self::create_barcode_code($id);

    $barcodeOptions = array('text' => $code, 'factor' => $factor, 'backgroundColor' => $backgroundColor, 'barHeight' => $barHeight, 'fontSize' => $fontSize);

    $rendererOptions = array('imageType' => 'gif');

    $image = Zend\Barcode\Barcode::factory('ean13', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->render();

    return $image;
}

private static function create_barcode_code($id)
{
    $code = str_pad($id, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return $code;
}
```

Issue is that in header I'm getting this weird chars and don't know how to get rid of it.

GIF87as>����,s>���j���qk�vc��=��ye�!�f�Z��\hv��:�ʰ���,����''�Т��Jji�n�C C}������m�=��E�N��m��V$82%g�����ǈ�g�Sy������9�C�RfyY�������$%jhZ:��ȩ X�)XGZzk[��+�K׊�wL|��ٛL�5k�����F]){�L>�l*]%>[��ޤ���}wl��=?M ��}���D\�v�| ���t�M[D�{V��`Fa���xB �x#�m��K��<,IB4���{Bb���1�)-� ���t:e��4�R� Q���aKhT�� ���֤.�z#zu�џR�����L45�r};Ԫ2|b�F=�1�ׅa׎��h)�z�����$^uNCe[0�ozy^�s?�g;��կh�' �����̣�|]���ճk�e\-��޼~;��o#w�<2qy�9�N�װ��ƫ^ߋ�/���mw���3��ݽ>��7�����?}�d����_Y?�o���|�I�_k�ٗ�l�%؂�58܃�aSrAw�|��Z�}� �n)�߆���Hb�PQB �h���<��Ӎ8��cx,� e���+Ij�P����O.9E��Pً��H1��F�QQ[���/j�tf�F�S�h�H�Wv�9'�w�)Ì:�L�\z�%�`��o y�J�&j�Y6�����i�� d�Dz:d� ���;�(�0��j��� k���P;

Comment: Which Kohana version is that?

Comment: Are you setting the Response's Content-Type header to 'image/gif'? I can't tell because You aren't showing :p

Comment: Yup but I think I've found answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to create another controller

```
class Controller_Barcode extends Controller_Base {

public function after()
{
    $this->response->headers('Content-Type','image/gif');
    parent::after();
}

public function action_Letter()
{
    Helper_Barcode::generate_barcode(Enum_Post::LETTER);
}
```

}

And in view:

```
 <img src="<?php echo '/Barcode/Letter'.$barcode; ?>">
```